# Understanding how to use OverScroller class

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scroll, android-overscoll

I'm looking into adding overscrolling (not the color changing) into my project, but even after reading the API docs and several questions on here I still don't really understand what I need to do to get it to work.

According to the API doc for OverScroller: "*this class encapsulates scrolling with the ability to overshoot the bounds of a scrolling operation. This class is a drop-in replacement for Scroller in most cases.*"

I had a Scroller object before in my parent class:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {   
    ....// code to calculate deltas
     if (deltaY != 0 || deltaX != 0)
            scrollBy(deltaX, deltaY);
}
```

And I went to change it to this:

```
if (deltaY != 0 || deltaX != 0)
            overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, getScrollX(), getScrollY(),
                child.getRight() - getWidth(), child.getBottom() - getHeight(), 
                    OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE, OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE, false);
```

And now scrolling doesn't work at all! `fling()` works fine as a drop in replacement but not scroll....

In summary I have two questions:

1. Why is scrolling not working with `overScrollBy`? Do I have to add additional code to make this work?
2. Why do I have to call `mScroller.fling()` and only `overScrollBy()`? Why not `mScroller.overScrollBy()`? Is it somehow built into the `View` class?

This may be potentially be quite obvious, but I'm struggling here. Any help would be most appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe because of this?

```
public class ViewConfiguration{
...
    /**
     * Max distance in dips to overscroll for edge effects
     */
    private static final int OVERSCROLL_DISTANCE = 0;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About `overScrollBy` the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#overScrollBy(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) says:

> Views that call this method should override `onOverScrolled(int, int, boolean, boolean)` to respond to the results of an over-scroll operation.

As you can find reading the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java), `overScrollBy` doesn't perform any scroll per se, but it calls `onOverScrolled` at the end.
So to make the scroll happens you should add to your View class something like:

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
}
```

`overScrollBy` is a method of the `View` class, intended to scroll the view content (through `onOverScrolled`).
The `OverScroller` class just makes some calculations of scrolling, e.g. with `mScroller.fling()` or `mScroller.springBack()`, but needs a further call to actually scroll the view content, tipically with:

```
@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        scrollTo(mScroller.getCurrX(), mScroller.getCurrY());
        invalidate();
    }
}
```